# Create new user with home directory inside another user's existing home directory -- both users must own the sub-directory

Tags: linux, permissions, users

Here's my situation:

- I have a user *storageUser* with a home directory of */storage*
- *storageUser* owns /storage with full (RWE) rights
- Within */storage* I have a directory *media*
- I'd like to create a new user *mediaUser* who's home directory is */storage/media* with read-only permissions while maintaining *storageUser*'s full RWE permissions

When using FTP or SSH to sign into the server, I'd like storageUser to be in control of /storage with full RWE permissions, while mediaUser only being able to read /storage/media. I'd like to give access to mediaUser in the future to share my media folder without people being able to make any changes.

Here's what I tried:

- Created *mediaUser* and set their password

```
useradd mediaUser
passwd mediaUser
...
```

- Created a new group *storageGroup*

```
groupadd storageGroup
```

- Added both *storageUser* and *mediaUser* to the group

```
usermod -a -G storageGroup storageUser
usermod -a -G storageGroup mediaUser
```

- Changed ownership permissions so that *storageUser* would have permission level 7 (read-write-execute) and *storageGroup* would have permission level 4 (read-only)

```
chown -R storageUser:storageGroup media
chmod -R 740 Media
```

- Changed the home directory of mediaUser

```
usermod -d /storage/media mediaUser
```

Permissions for *storageUser* seem to working OK, but when I SSH into the server as *mediaUser*, I get this error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /storage/media: Permission denied
```

*mediaUser* also cannot read directory contents with *ls*

```
ls: cannot access '/storage/media': Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "_both users must own the sub-directory_" - this isn't possible: you can only have one owner. Instead, please describe (in words) what you want to achieve

Comment: @ChrisDavies  Essentially, I want storageUser to be the main owner of /storage, but also have a second media user that can only read the media subdirectory. This is so that storageUser can edit, upload, and delete files, but I want to give access to other people to only be able to view/download from the media folder

Comment: @Omaro_IB Welcome, the whole concept of a user's *home* directory is that such user is the owner with their own settings, configurations and files. The goal you want to achieve doesn't seem related to *home* directories, but just group. permissions and ownership.

Comment: Try creating 2 users, each with their own home directories, even if they are never used, and then put both users you created in the same group.  Give members of that group rwx access to the same directory OUTSIDE OF the `/home/` directory.  This is what @shrodingerscat is referring to.

Comment: @Omaro_IB - what perms did you set on `/storage`? And the perms on `/storage/media` need to be `750`, not `740`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create Users

1. `useradd mediaUser`
2. `useradd storageUser`

### Setup Users

1. `passwd mediaUser`
2. `passwd storageUser`

### Create Group

1. `groupadd storageGroup`

### Create Directory

1. `mkdir /storage/media`

### Assign Users to Group

1. `usermod -a -G storageGroup {mediaUser,storageUser}`

### Change Owner of Directory to Group

1. `chgrp storageGroup /storage/media`

Now everyone in group `storageGroup` owns the particular directory.  Removing a user from `storageGroup` also removes access to that directory.  See also `man chgrp`  This method also removes the need for `storageUser`, unless you're using that user for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Beside users, groups, permissions and physical folders you can create soft or hard link with command `ln` which should make folders work as you expect. Entering the folder provided by link (shortcut) should work as it was real folder.

By default `ln` creates hard link, with option `-s` it creates soft link. Look into manual by `man ln`.

Comment: A soft link doesn't work because in order to access the original file, the user must have access to the directory the file is in (which is the entire issue), a hard link doesn't work either since it would require a cross-device link (/storage is mounted on an external disk)